# SSL for redirected domain to Azure app service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Hello I have created one app for Azure app service test.
Let us say myapp.azurewebsites.net
I thought this is big to recall so I own my domain. Say `www.xyzdomain.com`
I purchased one SSL from Azure portal and bind with `www.xyzdomain.com`
So `https://www.xyzdomain.com` working.

Now my client want to use this app with some custom domain.
I did redirection to `www.xyzdomain.com`

Now his domain is 
Let us say `www.hiscustomdomain.com`
So how should I proceed with this as they need SSL to secure like `https://www.hiscustomdomain.com`

He is asking me to raise CSR. I am using app service from Azure portal. Their is no VM.
Sorry for typo.

Thanks
Regards
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

You don't need access to the server to be able to generate a CSR. You can use any computer including your own workstation. See the link below for detailed instructions to create and complete a Certificate Signing Request.

https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-iis-10.htm

Once you complete the request, export the certificate from the computer you used to generate the CSR as .pfx format, upload and bind it to you Azure Web App.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl

Comment: Thanks Bruno. But I don't have IIS things configured on workstation. Windows 7 with no IIS enabled. There is long process to enable it with IT approval.
I want pfx certificate from client and I will upload it to Azure portal under custom domain for my working app service.
So to get pfx file from client I need CSR from side (from my workstation with some details like location etc.) If yes how?